# Add field with OneToOne relation in FOSUser register form

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I need your help to add some field in my register form in FOSUSerBundle.
I want to localize a user and save his latitude/longitude in the register form.
I create a oneToOne relation between my User entity and my Localisation entity, but I don't see where I could put my code to set the latitude and longitude of the user at the register phase.

Did I have to override the register controller, or some event ? I just don't see where put my code...

First, the documentation here is not updated for the new signature method : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md

This tutorial is ok but I don't see how use it with a oneToOne field... : 
http://www.idci-consulting.fr/fosuserbundle-comment-gerer-les-utilisateurs-avec-symfony2/

In fact, I add my relation in the User entity used for FOSUserBundle :

```
<?php

namespace rs\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\MessageBundle\Model\ParticipantInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements ParticipantInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="rs\UserBundle\Entity\Localisation", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $localisation;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set localisation
     *
     * @param \rs\UserBundle\Entity\Localisation $localisation
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLocalisation(\rs\UserBundle\Entity\Localisation $localisation = null)
    {
        $this->localisation = $localisation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get localisation
     *
     * @return \rs\UserBundle\Entity\Localisation 
     */
    public function getLocalisation()
    {
        return $this->localisation;
    }
}
```

Here is my Localisation entity :

```
<?php

namespace rs\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Localisation
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Localisation
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="decimal")
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="decimal")
     */
    private $longitude;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="rs\UserBundle\Entity\Clan", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $clan;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set latitude
     *
     * @param float $latitude
     * @return Localisation
     */
    public function setLatitude($latitude)
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get latitude
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getLatitude()
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Set longitude
     *
     * @param float $longitude
     * @return Localisation
     */
    public function setLongitude($longitude)
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get longitude
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getLongitude()
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }



    /**
     * Set clan
     *
     * @param \rs\UserBundle\Entity\Clan $clan
     * @return Localisation
     */
    public function setClan(\robStorm\UserBundle\Entity\Clan $clan = null)
    {
        $this->clan = $clan;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get clan
     *
     * @return \rs\UserBundle\Entity\Clan 
     */
    public function getClan()
    {
        return $this->clan;
    }
}
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to override/extend the existing RegistrationFormType. See [overriding forms](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) in the docs. In your type you add the location as sub form. So you have to create a LocationFormType too.

If you need to process some logig, you have to [hook into the controller with events](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md). Unfortunately events are only available in dev-master yet, not in the stable releases. If you forced to use the stable release, you have to [override the controller](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md) and copy all the logic from the old one and then add your logic.

Comment: In fact the latitude and longitude are defined with javascript script who use html5 géolocation.

I added two hidden input text in my register form and the js script set their value with latitude/longitude.

So there is no action from the user, there is no real input text, only js and two hidden field.
I have to create a LocationFormType with my two hidden field anyway ?